# image disappears when clicking on main image when using slick slider js carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, slick.js

I am using slick slider found here-https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ and I'm specifically using the slider syncing so that when someone clicks on an image in the carousel it will render that clicked image into a larger image next to the carousel and it is supposed to pop up in a lightbox type of thing when you click on that larger image. The issue is when you click one of those images in the carousel it loads that image in the larger image tag fine, but when you click on that larger image one or two of the images will disappear from the carousel. I am assuming I have something not set up in my javascript correctly. Any help with this would be appreciated I tried changing the "slidesToShow" and "slidesToScroll" values with no luck and I'm not really sure where to go from here, but here is my javascript within my html.

```
    $('.slider-cards_center').slick({
                    dots: false,
                    vertical: true,
                    infinite: true,
                    speed: 300,
                    slidesToShow: 5,
                    slidesToScroll: 1,
                    verticalSwiping: true,
                    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
                                        focusOnSelect: true,
                    responsive: [
                        {
                            breakpoint: 1024,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 1,
                                slidesToScroll: 1,
                                infinite: true,
                                dots: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 600,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 1,
                                slidesToScroll: 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 480,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 1,
                                slidesToScroll: 1
                            }
                        }

                    ]
    });

    $('.slider-for').slick({
                        dots: false,
                        infinite: true,
                        speed: 300,
                        slidesToShow: 1,
                        slidesToScroll: 1,
                        focusOnSelect: true,
                        asNavFor: '.slider-cards_center',
                        responsive: [
                        {
                            breakpoint: 1024,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 3,
                                slidesToScroll: 1,
                                infinite: true,
                                dots: false
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 600,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 3,
                                slidesToScroll: 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            breakpoint: 480,
                            settings: {
                                slidesToShow: 3,
                                slidesToScroll: 1
                            }
                        }

                    ]
    });
```

Comment: can you please post a workable snippet here.

Comment: Yes to ^^^. I don't see an obvious issue with your Slick implementation and need to see your markup, especially `.slider-cards_center`.

Comment: I will have to get back on that one. I'm using a CMS and I'm having trouble getting a snippet from the code I'm working with.

Comment: You could try to "view page source" in your browser and copy the relevant portion to your question.